# Watching select more efficient in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got 4 select boxes:

```
    <select class="selectize category"
            ng-options="stepType.id as stepType.title for stepType in filterOptions.stepTypes | orderBy:'title'"
            ng-model="filterSelections.stepType" >
        <option value="">All Steps</option>
    </select>

    <select class="selectize category"
            ng-options="manager.id as manager.title for manager in filterOptions.managers | orderBy:'title'"
            ng-model="filterSelections.manager" >
        <option value="">All Managers</option>
    </select>

    <select class="selectize category"
            ng-options="candidate.id as candidate.title for candidate in filterOptions.candidates | orderBy:'title'"
            ng-model="filterSelections.candidate" >
        <option value="">All Candidates</option>
    </select>

    <select class="selectize category"
            ng-options="position.id as position.title for position in filterOptions.positions | orderBy:'title'"
            ng-model="filterSelections.position" >
        <option value="">All Positions</option>
    </select>
```

And also i've got those watchers:

```
$scope.$watch('filterSelections.stepType', function(value)
{
    if (value == null) {
        return;
    }

    $scope.filter.step = value;

    $scope.fetch();

},true);

$scope.$watch('filterSelections.manager', function(value)
{
    if (value == null) {
        return;
    }

    $scope.filter.manager = value;

    $scope.fetch();

},true);

$scope.$watch('filterSelections.position', function(value)
{
    if (value == null) {
        return;
    }

    $scope.filter.manager = value;

    $scope.fetch();

},true);
```

is it possible to combaine all 3 watchers?

I know that you can for example use this syntax for all 3 watchers:

```
$scope.$watch('[filterSelections.position, filterSelections.manager, ...]', function(value)
{
    if (value == null) {
        return;
    }

    $scope.filter.manager = value;

    $scope.fetch();

},true);
```

But, how can I know from inside the watcher that its being called from manager or position?
also, what is the best way to handle such a behvaior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use `$watch` - use a `change` event, and pass in what you need (select name, and value) and make it work with them all:

```
$scope.selectChange = function(name, value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return;
    }

    $scope.filter[name] = value;

    $scope.fetch();
}
```

And the html:

```
<select class="selectize category"
        ng-options="stepType.id as stepType.title for stepType in filterOptions.stepTypes | orderBy:'title'"
        ng-model="filterSelections.stepType" ng-change="selectChange('stepType', filterSelections.stepType)" >
    <option value="">All Steps</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best choice is to use `ng-change` event like as said by @tymeJV in his **[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24656461/1575570)**, But If you are very much specific that you need to use `$watch` , try this

```
$scope.filterSelections = {};

$scope.$watch('filterSelections', function(value)
{
    if (value == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (filterSelections.manager)
    {
      $scope.filter.manager = value;
    }
    else if (filterSelections.candidate)
    {
      $scope.filter.candidate= value;
    }
    else if (filterSelections.position)
    {
      $scope.filter.position= value;
    }

    $scope.fetch();

},true);
```